# Delete method doesn't work rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I've made some updates to my app, but then It can't destroy existing category.

I just want to destroy existing category with confirmation.

Here my code

index.html.erb generating list of existing categories

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= category.category %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

categories_controller.erb actual controller i'm using

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /categories/new
  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /categories
  # POST /categories.json
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1
  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  # DELETE /categories/1.json
  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:category)
    end
end
```

model category.rb and the model containing has and belongs to many

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :blogs
end
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: What output do you get from running `rails routes`?

Comment: Check the server output. one possible reason is that you may be deleting a category which has many blogs - and rails / postgres might prevent you from doing that - becauase then you will have orphaned blogs. secondly, people generally don't use `has_and_belong_to_many` these days - they use `has_many` and then  `through`

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a diagnostic we can act on. What does it do? What does it log? What output do you get, if any?

Comment: I get this one from console after clicking destroy Started GET "/categories/2" for ::1 at 2020-06-29 12:10:59 +0200
Processing by CategoriesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:67:in `set_category'
  Rendering categories/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered categories/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 77)

Comment: Can you post your routes please?

Comment: sure Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories
  resources :blogs
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end

Comment: @Bongoja, I think they're wanting to see the terminal output when you enter `rake routes` as it relates to categories and blogs

Comment: category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#show  PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#update   PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#update DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#destroy

Comment: blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)  blogs#show
 PATCH  /blogs/:id(.:format) blogs#update
 PUT    /blogs/:id(.:format)     blogs#update
    DELETE /blogs/:id(.:format)                                                                     blogs#destroy

Comment: Clicking the "Destroy" link is sending a GET request. But it should send a POST request with the method: _delete flag. This behaviour will happen when Rails ujs is not present. So this is actually a javascript problem with the Rails ujs not being included on the page.